# Loop controls for label event (mousevove)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to ask about a simple repetition code from the code below. I want to simplify the following code to the form of repetition. for example for i = 1 to 24. etc.

**Edit:** seems to be making a long list of code if my label number is 50. thank you in advance for all the responses.

```
Private Sub Label11_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Label12.Visible = True
Label14.Visible = False
Label16.Visible = False
Label18.Visible = False
Label20.Visible = False
Label22.Visible = False
Label24.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub Label12_Click()
Label12.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Label13_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Label14.Visible = True
Label12.Visible = False
Label16.Visible = False
Label18.Visible = False
Label20.Visible = False
Label22.Visible = False
Label24.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub Label14_Click()
Label14.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Label15_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Label16.Visible = True
Label12.Visible = False
Label14.Visible = False
Label18.Visible = False
Label20.Visible = False
Label22.Visible = False
Label24.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub Label16_Click()
Label16.Visible = False
End Sub
```

from label 11 to 24 ....

Comment: can you explain in words what you would like to achieve? Edit your post to do that, then post a comment to alert the people who are following your question.

Comment: I just want to make a simple code from the code above. for example in the form of code reproduction. can you understand what i mean?